# Problem when inserting data in a partitioned View with Default constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server

Whereas I have the following database structure:

```
--SEQUENCE
CREATE SEQUENCE [seq_Table] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 0
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -9223372036854775808
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO


--TABLES
CREATE TABLE [Table_2019](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL, 
    [DataEmissao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Importado] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Versao] [varchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_2019_DataEmissao_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DataEmissao] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Table_2019] ADD  CONSTRAINT [CC_Table_2019_Select_New_Id]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [seq_Table]) FOR [Id]
ALTER TABLE [Table_2019] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_2019_Importado]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Importado]
ALTER TABLE [Table_2019]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CC_Table_2019_DataEmissao] CHECK  (([DataEmissao]>='2019-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND [DataEmissao]<'2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
ALTER TABLE [Table_2019] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CC_Table_2019_DataEmissao]


CREATE TABLE [Table_2020](
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL, 
    [DataEmissao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Importado] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Versao] [varchar](5) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_2020_DataEmissao_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DataEmissao] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Table_2020] ADD  CONSTRAINT [CC_Table_2020_Select_New_Id]  DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [seq_Table]) FOR [Id]
ALTER TABLE [Table_2020] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_2020_Importado]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Importado]
ALTER TABLE [Table_2020]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CC_Table_2020_DataEmissao] CHECK  (([DataEmissao]>='2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND [DataEmissao]<'2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'))
ALTER TABLE [Table_2020] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CC_Table_2020_DataEmissao]


-- VIEW
create view VWTESTE AS
SELECT * from [Table_2019]
UNION ALL
SELECT * from [Table_2020]
```

When I run the command:

```
--COMMAND
insert into VWTESTE ([DataEmissao], [Importado], [Versao]) values (Getdate(), 0, NULL)
```

I`m receiving the following error:

`Partitioned view 'BancoTeste.dbo.VWTESTE' is not updatable because table '[BancoTeste].[dbo].[Table_2019]' has a DEFAULT constraint.`

I found that the problem is because I have a constraint setting the value of the ID column as the default.
Are there any other ways for the database to automatically fill in the ID column other than triggers for this scenario? Or is the use of triggers is the best option?

Comment: You don't need partitioned views since SQL Server 2016 SP1. Partitioned tables are now available in [all editions, even Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSSP).

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, you saved me!!